# How do I adapt the number of required colors for a geom_bar plot automatically?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill, geom-bar

I would like to make a bar chart for a column with differently colored bars using ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
  geom_bar(fill = c("green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "black"))  +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

That works fine:
[image]
However, in such a small sample I cannot expect that all possible numbers are present. Here is an example, where this is the case:

```
set.seed(321)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Using the ggplot from before...

```
ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
  geom_bar(fill = c("green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "black"))  +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

...throws an error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill
```

It seems, that a vector with exactly 3 colors is expected, as there are 3 bars to fill?

Why is that?

Is there a way to fill without checking the numbers first?

And forcing a predefined number of bars (even when empty)?

**Edit:**

A solution was suggested by AndS.

```
set.seed(321)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(A1)))  +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

In this case that would result in 4 bars (including 1 empty bar).

However, to get all 5 bars (including missing bars), one has to label the data:

```
set.seed(321)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))

df_a[[1]] <- ordered(df_a[[1]], levels = c(0:4), labels = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))

ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(A1)))  +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Is there a way to avoid this? Like including the sampeling parameters to get the number of possible columns?

Number of required bars:

```
c_a <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c_a, 10, replace = TRUE))

length(c_a)
```

**edit2:**
I found a solution that works for me:

```
set.seed(321)

c_a <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c_a, 10, replace = TRUE))

df_a[[1]] <- ordered(df_a[[1]], levels = c_a, labels = as.character(c_a))

ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(A1)))  +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: in the `geom_bar` just write `aes(fill = as.factor(A1))`. That will give each bar a unique color without needing to preassign them.

Comment: @AndS. This works, but you get only one empty bar for seed 321.

Comment: For seed 321, you get an empty bar because there are no values for `x=3` and A1 is numeric. Thus if you pass `ggplot(df_a, aes(as.character(A1)))` there will be only three bars

Comment: @Romain Exactly, but that is not what I want.

Comment: if @AndS.'s suggestion doesn't work for you, I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want an empty bar for missing values or to remove the bar from the plot ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between giving the fill argument within the `aes()` call of `geom_bar` or outside of it. The error message you get is quite self-explanatory :

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill
```

- either you give only one color which will be the same for all bars (which is advised in general if the colors don't add meaning to the plot). In that case `geom_bar(fill="a color")` is enough :

```
df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))
ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
    geom_bar(fill = c("steelblue"))
```

- either you give a vector of colors which must be the same length of the data you're plotting. That's what suggested by @AndS.'s comment : if you convert `A1` to a factor, you obtain one unique color per value, and a vector of the same length as `A1`. In that case you must encapsulate the colors as an aesthetic for the plot : `geom_bar(aes(fill = as.factor(A1))`, because the fill values correspond to some data values in your dataframe (that is what are aesthetics in ggplot) :

```
df_a <- data.frame(A1 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), 10, replace = TRUE))
df_a$fill_value <- as.factor(df_a$A1)
ggplot(df_a, aes(A1)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = fill_value))
```

Comment: Note that the second plot adds a legend for the fill aesthetic, which is a good sign from ggplot2 that these values *should* mean something more than what is already said by the x axis